# Kotlin validate edittext for entry and length

Tags: validation, kotlin

We have an EditText that is inputType numberDecimal and we can validate the number entered and if no value was entered. Our question is how to incorporate both in to one if statement or is this even possible. The code below runs with no issues until we try to add this length test to the value enter test with this line of code
**if( F.toInt() < 1 || S.toInt() > 7 || L ==0  ){**

```
    fun weekDAY(view: View?){

    val L:Int = etValOne.length()
    if(L == 0){

        toast("Check The Entry\nValid Entry 1 to 7")
        return@weekDAY
    }

    val F: String = etValOne.text.toString()
    val S: String = etValOne.text.toString()

    if( F.toInt() < 1 || S.toInt() > 7 ){
        toast("Check The Entry\nValid Entry 1 to 7")
        return@weekDAY
    }

    var dayOfWeek: String = etValOne.text.toString()
    var dayOfWeekInString = when(dayOfWeek.toInt()) {
        1 -> "Monday"
        2 -> "Tuesday"
        3 -> "Wednesday"
        4 -> "Thursday"
        5 -> "Friday"
        6 -> "Saturday"
        7 -> "Sunday"
        else -> "Invalid Day"
    }

    etANS.setText(dayOfWeekInString)
}
```

We understand the else statement in the when method we are trying to develop ERROR trapping methodology. Yes we have looked at other posts that is how we were able to write the two error check. No post had both values checked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you have duplicate unnecessary coding.  
I try to simplify it:

```
fun weekDAY(view: View?){
    val F: String = etValOne.text.toString().trim()
    val L: Int = F.length
    var value = 0
    try {
        value = F.toInt()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
    }

    if((L == 0) || (value !in 1..7)) {
        toast("Check The Entry\nValid Entry 1 to 7")
        return@weekDAY
    }

    val dayOfWeekInString = when(value) {
        1 -> "Monday"
        2 -> "Tuesday"
        3 -> "Wednesday"
        4 -> "Thursday"
        5 -> "Friday"
        6 -> "Saturday"
        7 -> "Sunday"
        else -> "Invalid Day"
    }

    etANS.setText(dayOfWeekInString)
}
```

As you can see you need to get the string from the EditText `etValOne` only once: `F` 
Then you get its length: `L`  
then you get the numeric value: `value` surrounded by try/catch so if the string is empty or not numeric the app will not crash.  
After that you have only 1 `if` that checks both the lengh and the value.  
 
The `else` part of the `when` statement will never be executed.  
If you want the string `"Invalid Day"` to be displayed in the EditText `etANS` in case of invalid value then this must be coded inside the `if` block.  
The above code can be **simplified** even **more** (but I kept your original logic) like this:

```
fun weekDAY(view: View?){
    val F: String = etValOne.text.toString().trim()
    var value = 0
    try {
        value = F.toInt()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
    }

    val dayOfWeekInString = when(value) {
        1 -> "Monday"
        2 -> "Tuesday"
        3 -> "Wednesday"
        4 -> "Thursday"
        5 -> "Friday"
        6 -> "Saturday"
        7 -> "Sunday"
        else -> {
            toast("Check The Entry\nValid Entry 1 to 7")        
            "Invalid Day"
        }
    }
    etANS.setText(dayOfWeekInString)
}
```

This way **you don't need to check explicitly the length** because if it is 0 then a `NumberFormatException` will be caught by the `catch` statement and the variable `value` will remain 0. So the `when` statement later on will return `"Invalid Day"`

Comment: The second iteration is really SMART code and CLEAN We can see where we need to increase our knowledge about try catch and possible exceptions use The first iteration if statement has very useful syntax TXH

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Though the above answer is correct but I would like to add something. Value to editText should not be set inside the method body rather it should return the valid day or error. Function will be doing its stand-alone task in this way and will be testable.

```
fun weekDAY(view: View?) : String{
    val F: String = etValOne.text.toString().trim()
    var value = 0
    try {
        value = F.toInt()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
    }

    return when(value) {
        1 -> "Monday"
        2 -> "Tuesday"
        3 -> "Wednesday"
        4 -> "Thursday"
        5 -> "Friday"
        6 -> "Saturday"
        7 -> "Sunday"
        else -> {
            toast("Check The Entry\nValid Entry 1 to 7")
            "Invalid Day"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We see one issue with this which is not a problem BUT for clarity if anyone tries to use this code you need to declare the var value - 0 GLOBALLY and you need a second fun to call weekDAY which in our case is the onCLICK of a BUTTON also use this to populate the EditText etANS.setText(value.toString()) We do not know enough about OVERHEAD to debate the benefit of one fun vs two fun Nice to outside the BOX thinking